# How to generate exponential variate without negative numbers in Python?

Tags: python, random, exponential

How to generate exponential variate without negative numbers in Python?

I tried to use this code but it generates negative number

```
>>> import random
>>> int(random.expovariate(0.28)
5
```

I thought about using if statement, but it'll affect my randomness and my final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [`random.expovariate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.expovariate):

> Exponential distribution. lambd is 1.0 divided by the desired mean. It should be nonzero. (The parameter would be called “lambda”, but that is a reserved word in Python.) Returned values range from 0 to positive infinity if lambd is positive, and from negative infinity to 0 if lambd is negative.

If you want non-negative results, use non-negative arguments.